# Hide multiple rows based on multiple ranges cell value VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, is-empty

I have a sheet (Sheet3) within a workbook that I would like to write VBA to hide multiple rows based on cell value in multiple ranges.  The VBA would have to run through two different steps; the first would be if the first cell within the specified range is blank then hide the entire range (except range 1 since the first cell would never be blank).  The second step would be if the first cell in range is not blank, then hide rows in that range that are blank.  Here are the specifics:

Range 1

1. A11:A60 - Hide rows that are blank in range

Range 2

2. A71:A120 - If cell A71 is blank, Hide A71:A120. Otherwise hide all rows that are blank in range A71:A120.

Range 3

3. A131:A180 - If cell A131 is blank, Hide A131:A180.  Otherwise hide all rows that are blank in range A131:A180.

Range 4

4. A191:A240 - If cell A191 is blank, Hide A191:A240.  Otherwise hide all rows that are blank in range A191:A240.

Range 5

5. A251:A300 - If cell A251 is blank, Hide A251:A300.  Otherwise hide all rows that are blank in range A251:A300.

   ```
   Public Sub HideRowsSummary()
   Dim wsMySheet As Worksheet
   Dim lngMyRow  As Long, unionRng As Range
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For Each wsMySheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      Select Case wsMySheet.Name
       Case Is = Sheet3
           .Range("A11:A60", "A71:A120", "A131:A180", "A191:A240", "A251:A300").EntireRow.Hidden = False
               For lngMyRow = 11 To 60
                   If Len(.Range("A" & lngMyRow)) = 0 Then
                       If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                           Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Range("A" & lngMyRow))
                       Else
                           Set unionRng = .Range("A" & lngMyRow)
                       End If
                   End If
               Next lngMyRow
           End With
       End Select
       If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
       Set unionRng = Nothing
   Next wsMySheet
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: You will need to show some code. I would start with unhiding rows in all the ranges then loop each range with initial test of isblank first cell, if is blank add entire range to Union and exit for, move onto next range repeat. If not blank then don't exit and continue looping adding each blank row to Union. At very end test if Union of range is nothing and hide the union range variable if applicable.

Comment: Or <>vbNullString may be more appropriate.

Comment: you could take a look at this answer for inspiration :p https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790344/2727437 but note that it does not first un-hide cells

Comment: All of the cells within the ranges will be visible to start so the code wont need that part.

Answer (score 1):

In your question `#2, 3, 4, 5` all follow similar logic.

The first `i` loop tackles `#1`. The next portion of the code tackles `#2`. You can simply copy/paste the bottom portion and change your test values to complete your ask.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideMe()

Dim i As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    For i = 11 To 60
        .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = .Range("A" & i) = vbNullString
    Next i

    'Repeat this portion for you other ranges that follow the same rules
    If .Range("A" & 71) = vbNullString Then
        .Range("A71:A120").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        For i = 72 To 120
            .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = .Range("A" & i) = vbNullString
        Next i
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

---

This can be improved by

A) Use `For Each` loop instead of `For i` loop
B) Instead of hiding rows one by one, add them to a collection of rows as a (`Union`) and hide the `Union` all at once

Comment: OP did this work or what? I see that you commented above and did not address the solution :)